# How to check result of FileManager.default.setUbiquitous()

Tags: ios, swift, multithreading, cocoa

I am making a document-based iOS app in Swift which uses `FileManager.default.setUbiquitous()` to save files to the app's iCloud Drive folder. Right now, I can not find a way to determine when `setUbiquitous` successfully runs (as I mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44099027/wait-for-file-to-upload-before-running-swift-function) post).

I was going through Apple's documentation, and it says that the Objective-C version of `setUbiquitous()` returned a `Bool`, while

> In Swift, this method returns Void and is marked with the throws
>   keyword to indicate that it throws an error in cases of failure.

I want to know when this function runs successfully so that I can run other code to account for the uploaded document - the closest way I have found to do this is in the function's description, which says:

> use a dispatch queue to call this method from background thread. After
>   the method returns, message your main thread to update the rest of
>   your app’s data structures.

The problem is, I don't know what it means by "messaging your main thread to update the rest of your app's data structures". Any help with this would be much appreciated!

Edit: After looking into this further, I think my main issue is where it says "after the method returns...". If the method only returns 'Void', how can I wait until it returns to update the rest of the data structures?

Answer (score 2):

Here's the general idea:

```
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
    // This will run on a background Thread

    let succeeded: Bool
    try {
        FileManager.default.setUbiquitous( ... )
        succeeded = true
    }
    catch {
        // handle error
        succeeded = false
    }

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        // This will run back on the main thread
        reportResult(succeeded)
    }
}
```

Comment: This still runs the 'reportResult()' function before the file is done loading. Is there a way to pause the function on the background thread until the file is saved?

Comment: @Grant Odd, I thought `setUbiquitous` was a synchronous function.